# Why is the parameter is not updated?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I have a class that uses another class.

The first class have this method:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    //Parameters are an enumeration.
    // Really is a exchange variable between this class
    //and the other class.
    Paramters myParameter = Parameters.Option1;

    MyClass2 myOtherClass = new MyClass2(myParameter);
}
```

The second class:

```
public enum Parameters { Option1, Option2, Option3 }

MyClass2
{
    Parameters _myParameters;

    Public MyClass2(Parameters paramParameters)
    {
        _myParameters = paramParameters;
    }

    private void clickButton()
    {
        _myParameters = Parameters.Option2;
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What I what it is create a dialog and `Parameters` are an enumeration that is to serve as exchange between the main window and the dialog to notify about the selection in the dialog.

However, when in the `clickButton` I change the value of the `_myParameters`, it is not changed in the object that was passed as parameter in the constructor of `MyClass2`.

If instead of using an enumeration as exchange variable I create a class that has the enumeration, then I can get the selection. The exchange class would be like this:

```
class MyExchangeClass
{
    Parameters myOption;
}
```

Then the code would be:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    //Parameters are an enumeration. 
    // Really is a exchange variable between this class
    //and the other class.
    MyExchangeClass mySelection= new MyExchangeClass();

    MyClass2 myOtherClass = new MyClass2(mySelection);
}
```

The second class:

```
public MyExchangeClass
{
    Parameters enum MySelection { Option1, Option2, Option3 }
}

class MyClass2
{
    MyExchangeClass _mySelection;

    Public MyClass2(MyExchangeClassparamParameters)
    {
        _mySelection= paramParameters;
    }

    private void clickButton()
    {
        _mySelection.MySelection = Parameters.Option2;
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In this way, the `Class1`, the main window, gets the updated  value in the property of the `class MyExchangeClass`.

I would like to know why in the first solution the enumeration is not updated, because if it would possible, I would like to avoid the needed to wrap the enumeration in a class.

Comment: is your clickButton wired up to the button?  It doesn't appear to be

Comment: well the click button it is to show that the _MySelection is updated, that is a class variable of the Class2, but it seems that is not the same variable that the parameter of the constructor, although is assigned on the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, when in the clickButton I change the value of the _myParameters, is not changed in the object that was passed as parameter in the constructor of MyClass2.

No, it wouldn't be. The value was passed in by value - the two variables (`myParameter` and `_myParameters`) are independent variables. A change to one variable does not affect the other variable. This is how *all* types work in C#.

For changes to a parameter *within a method* to be seen by the caller, you could use a `ref` parameter, but that's not viable in your case as you're changing an *instance* variable which was originally populated via a parameter.

You could wrap the value in a mutable class, pass a reference to an instance of that class into `MyClass2`, and then mutate the object within `MyClass2` - *that* change would be seen within your first class, because that would be changing the data within the object rather than the instance variable of `MyClass2`. It's hard to know whether or not that's actually a good solution though, as we have so little context - with names like `MyClass` and `myMethod` we have no clue as to the bigger picture of what this is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

In your first solution the value of the enumeration inside the class didn't change because enumeration is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), and this line:

```
_myParameters = paramParameters;
```

made a copy of `paramParameters` and `_myParameters` is a completely separate, standalone object.

In your second example, `MyExchangeClass` is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), so this line:

```
_mySelection= paramParameters;
```

made `_mySelection` point to exactly the same object as `paramParameters` reference was referring to.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx):

> Variables that are based on value types directly contain values. Assigning one value type variable to another copies the contained value. This differs from the assignment of reference type variables, which copies a reference to the object but not the object itself.

And an enumeration is a value type, ibidem:

> The value types consist of two main categories:
>
> - Structs
> - Enumerations